# LaTex or MathML rendering

Tags: math, browser, mathjax

I have a formula in LaTex or MathML and I want to render it on a browser, I try MathJax but is so slow, there is another javascript for render some formula faster the mathjax?

Comment: Just one formula?  If so, then generate an image and use that.  Or are you trying to handle many different formulas?

Comment: no there are some page with 1,2,3,4 formula...before now I use image but now i need to have something faster! The browser render MathML for default but is a bit bad graphically...

Answer (score 1):

For tex-like input you could give jqmath a try, it is much smaller and faster than mathjax (but doesn't try to do such a complete job) http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html

For MathML input webkit and firefox now support that by default but getting math fonts installed by default on the platforms is still an issue, and it may take a while for the mathml support to reach all relevant browsers. For example MathML is in Chrome 24 released last week, but neither the mobile version of chrome (nor the android stock browser) use a new enough webkit base at present. Obviously the built in MathML support will be a lot faster than a javascript implementation.

Comment: Note jqMath will use the browser's built-in MathML support if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use this: [WP Latex](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-latex/)